# Check whether the volume button is pressed while shaking the phone?

Tags: android, sensormanager

I want to pause or resume my music when shaking the phone.

The problem is, while walking around with the phone in my pocket, the phone shake event is called by accident sometimes.

So, I want to combine the volume or on/off button with shaking the phone. How can I find out, whether the volume button is pressed at the moment.

I tried this, but this is only working when my app is in the forground. Is there a possiblity just to get the state, whether it is pressed at the moment or not, without a onkeydown listener?

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        //Do something
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: just curious, but wouldnt this always min or max your current volume? which would be quite annoying as this app is supposed to be running when you listen to music :)

Comment: only when the screen is on. An other possibility would be to listen for the on off key.

Comment: then you would need to press 1x the powerbutton, then keep the volume-button pressed and shake the phone.... for clicking play!?

Comment: No, when the powerbutton is not pressed before the volume buttons not changing the volume. I only want to shake the standby phone with the volume buttons pressed.

Comment: well you need a VolumeButtonReceiver then. And it can handle the listening of the shaking. Though i doubt that you can detect the shaking when the screen is off.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the volume button is disabled when the phone is in standby. The shaking is still working, when I don't unregister the ShakeEventListener. So I have to live with shaking without pressing a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @sativa i think you can do it by using device sensor property which normally uses at time of calling, you can check if the device is in pocket or not, just like when we make call screen is gone to be lock if we keep our device closer to our ears. Think in this direction may be it will help you